# Retrieving pages from what.cd

Tags: python, cookies, screen-scraping

I'm working on a screen scraper using BeautifulSoup for what.cd using Python.  I came across [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18284740/whatget.py) script while working and decided to look at it, since it seems to be similar to what I'm working on.  However, every time I run the script I get a message that my credentials are wrong, even though they are not.

As far as I can tell, I'm getting this message because when the script tries to log into what.cd, what.cd is supposed to return a cookie containing the information that lets me request pages later in the script.  So where the script is failing is:

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username,
                               'password' : password})
check = opener.open('http://what.cd/login.php', login_data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(check.read())
warning = soup.find('span', 'warning')
if warning:
    exit(str(warning)+'\n\nprobably means username or pw is wrong')
```

I've tried multiple methods of authenticating with the site including using CookieFileJar, the script located [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#id5), and the Requests module.  I've gotten the same HTML message with each one.  It says, in short, that "Javascript is disabled", and "Cookies are disabled", and also provides a login box in HTML.

I don't really want to mess around with Mechanize, but I don't see any other way to do it at the moment.  If anyone can provide any help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't it have to be a POST? And don't you need `&login=Login` as well?

Comment: What do you mean?  Sorry but could you provide a code sample or clarify more, I'm a little confused.

Comment: @bzlm means you're making a GET request when the server is expecting a POST and you're missing the login=Login parameter.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm just guessing. Also, there are (allegedly) working examples on the site itself in the forums. :)

Comment: @bzlm Yeah, I've looked at the "allegedly" working examples (this script being one of them) and haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more hours of searching, I found the solution to my problem.  I'm still not sure why this code works as apposed to the version above, but it does.  Here is the code I'm using now:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

request = urllib2.Request("http://what.cd/index.php", None)
f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
f.close()

data = urllib.urlencode({"username": "your-login", "password" : "your-password"})
request = urllib2.Request("http://what.cd/login.php", data)
f = urllib2.urlopen(request)

html = f.read()
f.close()
```

Credit goes to carl.waldbieser from [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/python-logging-into-a-site-352040/).  Thanks for everyone who gave input.